# How to switch into default Rails console from the pre-rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I have recently installed the pry-rails gem for debugging purpose but when I entered the command  "rails c" for logging into a console its direct me to the pry-rails console.

How to switch into the default console instead of pry-rails console without uninstalling the pry-rails gem.

Thanks & Regards,
 Krishnan.K

Comment: hello can u try "Ctrl+d" command

Comment: No it is not working..:(

Comment: Try `bundle exec rails c`

Comment: Nope.. bundle exec rails c command also direct me to the pre-rails console mode only..